# Why array is not changed?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

There is a service that manages the list using `set/get` methods:

```
@Injectable()
export class ListService {
    private items: any[] = [];

    getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }

    setItems<T>(items: T[]): T[] {
        this.items = [...items];
        return this.items;
    }

    setSelected(value: any): void {
        value.selected = !value.selected;
    }

    setSelectedState(value: any, state: boolean): void {
        value.selected = state;
    }

    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        moveItemInArray(this.items, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }

    emitChnages(): void {
        this.onChanged.next(this.items);
    }
}
```

I use this service inside component,  the input variable `packet` I assign to `this.listService.setItems()`:

```
export class SignComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() packet: any;
   public copysogllist: any[] = [];
   ngOnInit() {
        this.copysogllist = this.listService.setItems(this.packet.sogllist);
    }

       public drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>): void {
         this.listService.drop(event);
        
    }
}
```

Why when I call `this.listService.drop(event);` it does not change array `this.copysogllist`?

Comment: Where did you subscribe the observable?

Comment: What? I dont use subscription I pass array `setItems<T>(items: T[]): T[] {}` then call drop method in service that move element of array

Comment: You're copying the array. Why do you expect the original array to change?

Comment: I copy but then I return copied array to componen's varaible `this.copysogllist `

Comment: What does `moveItemInArray()` do?

Comment: Are you sure `drop()` is called?

Comment: Yes, I call from component

Comment: The `moveItemInArray()` is martial CDK drag/dtop in list

Comment: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Comment: You’re only setting your value once in ngOnInit.. as a service call. You should use an observable in your service and subscribe in your component to get the changes.

Comment: Why I can not change array buy reference?

Comment: @asad how do you understand the array is not changed? if you are using OnPush and call [moveItemInArray](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-utils.ts#L15) which actually modify the array then appropriate changes will not be reflected in the UI

Comment: It’s a valid question. The issue here I think is that there is no actual change to the array, the instance stays the same, therefore there is no way for Angular to know that something changed.

Comment: @asad you are probably using `OnPush`, you need to call `markForCheck`, because the array reference doesn't change, just the contents. Better would be to have an `Observable` approach

Comment: No, I dont use onPush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 you can just make 

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        moveItemInArray(this.items, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);

     return this.items
    }
    
and in your component

public drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>): void {
         this.copysogllist = this.listService.drop(event);
        
    }
```

Comment: btw if you use this variable another page which you can't handle with inputs you should see ngrx. That's perfect solution for that kind of problems